# in javascript dom, are there rules to attribute names?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, attributes

for meta data on the page using attribute names like `table:rowNum:<name>`, eg,

```
var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.setAttribute('tup','emp:1');
row.setAttribute('emp:1:pkid','123');
```

have been using colon-delimited names (eg, `name='emp:1:emp_id'`) for years with good success, but today got bit with colon delimited attribute names

in particular:

```
var el2 = row.parentNode.querySelector("[emp:1:pkid]");
=> `Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12`
```

are special character like ':' illegal in dom attribute names?  can special characters be escaped to work with `querySelector()`?

---

from chrome console:

```
> row.parentNode.querySelector('[emp:1:pkid]');
Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
```

as per James (below):

```
> row.parentNode.querySelector('[emp\\:1\\:pkid]');
123
```

but Problem - does not work with `getAttribute` - pia

```
> row.getAttribute('emp:1:pkid');
123
> row.getAttribute('emp\\:1\\:pkid');
null
```

Comment: interesting and I'm not sure yet (looking it up).  In the meantime, for future projects, consider using jQuery's `data()`.  It lets you set any arbitrary data and associate it with your dom elements (both from the server so your js can use it and client-side only.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: DOM attributes are of type DOMString which is a UTF-16 encoded sequence. As far as I can tell the characters you're using should be fine. I'm not 100% sure on that though hence the comment rather than answer.

Comment: @cc young - `querySelector('[emp\\:1]')` will return `null` because it doesn't match an element (based on the example you originally posted). Did you mean `[emp\\:1\\:update]`?

Comment: @James - sorry about the sloppy example.  it was the `DOM Execption 12` that I was focusing on.  will fix example to be consistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you can escape the special characters with a double backslash:

```
var el2 = element.querySelector("[emp\\:1\\:update]");
```

I think the problem is to do with the fact that a colon would normally indicate a pseudo element.

According to the [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tokenization.html#before-attribute-name-state), any characters except those that would change the context (e.g. an equals character, as that specifies the start of the value, or a greater-than character, which would specify the end of the tag). On that basis, it's fine to use colon characters in attribute names.

**Update** (based on comments on answer and updates on question)

To use one variable with both `querySelector` and `getAttribute`, you could do something like this, or you could just store the version with escaped characters, and one without (which would definitely be my preferred option):

```
var s = "emp\\:1\\:update";
console.log(row.getAttribute(s.replace(/\\/g, "")));
```

Comment: good insight, but problem: works fine with `querySelector()` but _fails_ with `getAttribute()` - see problem area for example

Comment: Get rid of the square brackets. `getAttribute` takes the entire string passed to it as the name of the attribute.

Comment: square brackets: problem with cut and paste on the example text.  problem remains.

Comment: Why don't you just not escape them when using `getAttribute`?

Comment: to be clear, your solution works.  the problem is that the program needs to maintain two copies of the attribute name, one for `getAttribute` and another for `querySelector` - seems that's a pia that might have to be lived with

Comment: I think that's going to be your best option. See update to my answer for a different solution. However, I would probably just use two!

Comment: The reason why you can't use same string with `querySelector` and `getAttribute` both, because `querySelector` uses CSS rules to query elements by attribute, and within this rules you should escape semicolon with backslash, e.g. `emp\:1\:pkid` (within CSS semicolon have special meanings). `getAttribute`, on the other side, accepcts plain HTML names, e.g. `emp:1:pkid`.